# Application works on tomcat but in Glassfish NetBeans is showing 404 error

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I developed a small web application with Glassfish Netbeans IDE.  It works on tomcat but in Glassfish NetBeans is showing 404 error. This is my code:

```
<h1> click one hyperlink </h1>
<a href="turl?p1=link1"> All Languages </a>
<br> <br> <br/>
<a href="turl?p1=link2"> All Countries </a>
<br><br><br/>
<a href="turl?p1=link3"> System Properties </a>
<br> <br> <br/>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.nt.TestSrv1</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/turl</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>page.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**java code**

```
package com.nt;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Locale;

public class TestSrv1 extends HttpServlet 
{
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        //General Settings
        PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        //read p1 req parameter values
        String pval=req.getParameter("p1");
        if(pval.equals("link1"))
        {
            Locale lcle[]=Locale.getAvailableLocales();
            for(Locale lc:lcle)
            {
                pw.println("<br>"+lc.getDisplayLanguage());
            }
        }
        else if(pval.equals("link2"))
        {
            Locale lcle[]=Locale.getAvailableLocales();
            for(Locale lc:lcle)
            {
                pw.println("<br>"+lc.getDisplayCountry());
            }
        }
        else
            pw.println("System Properties: "+System.getProperties());

        pw.close();
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        doGet(req,res);
    }

}
```

Comment: Any errors when the application is starting?

Comment: no i'm getting any starting errors in glassfish,but browser does't show the application.